# Original position of a draggable in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, droppable

As a drop happens, I need to recover the original position of the draggable:

```
$('.article').droppable( {

    drop: function(even, ui){

        // ui.draggable.???
    }
});
```

Since there is a "revert: "invalid" property on my draggable, I assume the original position is store somewhere. How can I find it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use: `ui.helper.position()`

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/atagax/2/edit)*

```
var startPos;
$( ".article" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    start: function(evt, ui){
        startPos = ui.helper.position();
    }
});

$(".parent").droppable({
    drop: function(evt, ui){
        // NOW RETRIEVE COORDINATES STORED BY THE DRAGGABLE :START
        var x = startPos.left;
        var y = startPos.top;
        alert(x+' '+y);
    }
});
```

Comment: When you drag an element then drag it back out, if you attempt to drag it back in, it gets rejected, any workaround for this?

Comment: @DannyG I don't get your question. Nothing gets rejected in the example above.